# Displaying dual monitor screenshot in "dual fullscreen" mode

Tags: windows-7, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

Suppose I take a PNG screenshot on a dual monitor system (let's assume for simplicity they are identical), The screenshot will capture both monitors. Now say I want to display that screenshot in an image viewer (windows photo viewer, xnview, etc) at fullscreen - I will then have to choose which monitor to display it on, distorting the image. Is there a way to strech it accross both monitors (aside of changing the windows display mode in the screen configuration window) ?

I am using Windows 7

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard Windows 7 picture/image viewer can be resized (stretch with the mouse) across multiple monitors, allowing images too large to fit on one monitor to be shown at closer to 1:1.

Comment: Thanks (upvoted), though I was hoping for something more native to the program than manual resizing (ideally true dual fullscreen)